# Why is residual strong force needed?

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, strong-force

I was wondering why the residual force was needed to hold nucleons together? If the net charge resides on the surface and acts perpendicular to the surface [(page I found, though not about nuclei)](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gausur.html), how is there an electromagnetic repulsion to counteract if they point in different directions? And wouldn't the recoil from the surface protons emitting photons push the nucleus together?

Comment: What do you mean by “net charge resides on the surface”? Please do not think about classical charge distributions for nucleons and as if the nucleus of an atom is a “surface” or sphere. In quantum mechanics things are very different. Charge is discrete and particles are probability waves.

Comment: Hi, Wecome to Physics Stack Exchange. our attempts to descride the microscopic world are based on models, which get more and sophisticated (i.e complicated;) as we progess in our understanding. The page you cited (a Gaussian surface) does not actually say that any charge resides on the surface, as there really is no surface to reside on, even in the classical model with the Gaussian surface referred to.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think I'd better keep reading!

Comment: This is a very good book, related to your question which I "found" on searching the web: Introduction to Elementary Particles Paperback, David Griffiths. Best of luck with it.